# React - show loader while child nodes are loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal window component that can take any type of HTML - inline, img tags, iframes etc.

Is it possible for the component to detect if the children have loaded?

An example:

```
// app
<myComp>
    <img src="some/remote/image.png" alt="" />
</myComp>

// myComp
render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    // Pseudo code
    const childrenLoading = children !== 'loading'; // <<< Possible to detect this??

    return(
        <div>
            {childrenLoading ? '<p>loading</p>' : children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I have looked into the React lifecycle methods, specifically componentDidUpdate, but of course myComp is not receiving new child data so it it doesn't trigger as an update.

Perhaps it is not possible because the image / iframe is loading outside of my React app. If I'm wrong please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just have the children handle the logic if displaying `loading`?

Comment: Can you show how have you called `childrenLoading` component in its parent?

Comment: With img tags you could use the onLoad event. See if it helps: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#image-events

Comment: I think you need redux:  https://redux.js.org/ you can use loader via redux reducer it calculates the next state and returns a new object depending on the action type.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. II have gone with loading the image inside my react app so I can control the onload events as @iguatemi-garin stated.

Comment: @EJP I'm glad to help. I'll write it as an answer then. Thanks

Comment: Made demo on your scenario, check this code once and let me know is this you need. [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-componentdidmount?embed=1&file=Hello.js].

Answer (score 1):

Use the onLoad event of the img tag to communicate with the children component.

```
<img onLoad={this.handleOnLoad} src="//the-src-of-the-image" />
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#image-events